How do I grant permission for an application to read Azure billing data?
I am trying to set up an application to automatically download consumption and billing data from the Azure management APIs. I have set up an app registration and installed it as an Enterprise Application in the tenant I want to pull data from, and I can get a token using the MSAL library just fine. I have granted the application user read access to the root billing (the tenant is on an Enterprise Agreement, which works differently to an MCA, which doesn't help). This token can successfully read the list of subscriptions out of the Graph API. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/subscriptions/list?view=rest-resources-2022-12-01&tabs=HTTP)
However, when I try to get data from e.g. the List Reservation Summaries endpoint, I get 401 Unauthorised. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/consumption/reservations-summaries/list?view=rest-consumption-2023-05-01&tabs=HTTP).
What sort of setup do I need to do for the application to have access to this endpoint? Do I need to create a user account that has access and have the application sign in as that user?
The app currently has these permissions assigned:


Could you include full error message that you are getting when you ran List Reservation Summaries endpoint? And what type of subscription you currently have?

@Sridevi Hi, the response I get is this: {"error":{"code":"Unauthorized","message":"Caller is not authorized","details":null}}; there are 79 different subscriptions underneath the root agreement, which is why I want to pull the data automatically.

Check if this helps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1191216/what-caller-is-not-authorized-means The error might occur if you are using wrong scope instead of billing account info.

@Sridevi the scope I am using is 'providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingAccounts/{billingAccountId}' - copied straight from the documentation page (with the billing account ID filled in when I use it). The linked page on that question doesn't help because you can't grant those roles to an app, only a user account.

Got it. For assigning roles to service principal or application, check this MS Doc if it helps  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/assign-roles-azure-service-principals

Regarding roles required to access Azure Reservations, check this MS Doc if it helps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/reservations/view-reservations

It turns out that what is needed is to add the EnrolmentReader role to the service principal for the application. An admin for the target tenant needs to either run a script or make an API call to create a role assignment, as detailed in this page:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/assign-roles-azure-service-principals?toc=%2Fazure%2Fcost-management-billing%2Ftoc.json#assign-enrollment-account-role-permission-to-the-spn
I have found that it's easiest to generate the script.
